# Analytic continuation of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^{n+1}}{n+1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-continuation

I'm asked to discuss the analytic continuation of the function

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^{n+1}}{n+1}$$ for |z|<1

The following hint is also provided

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^{n+1}}{n+1} = \int_{0}^{z}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^{*n}dz^*$$

I'm unsure how to interpret the problem. What can be said about its analytic continuation? Is the integral providing a clue as to where it can be continued?

Comment: Geometric series? Logarithm? ;o)

Comment: Oh wow... thanks!

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp So the function can be analytically continued to all z, excluding z=+1 and the branch cut of log? Note: I found the given series to be equivalent to $-log(1-z)$.

Comment: @Jay You have it correct.  The A.C. is $-\log(1-z)$ on the plane less a branch cut from $z=1$ to $\infty$.